# Open keyboard for EditText inside a TextView

Tags: android, spinner, soft-keyboard

I have a Spinner(inside a dialog) that contains an EditText as one of its element.
The problem is that no keyboard is shown when I click inside the EditText.
I tried various methods like manually opening the softkeyboard with  the InputMethodManager  whenever there is an OnClick or OnItemSelected event occurs but none of these worked for me.

Any tips?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: post the code  which u tried...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
InputMethodManager m = (InputMethodManager) 
  if(m != null){
      m.toggleSoftInput(0, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
   }
```

Comment: Thanks the keyboard did open though it is shown behind the spinnerlist. I'll try to do something about it.